# Write UTF-8 textfile with Python that Windows Editor can read

Tags: python, windows, unicode, utf-8, editor

I use Python 3.4 on Win 7 and have the following problem:

I'd like to write a multiline unicode text to a text file which the user can open with the standard Windows Editor (I know ...) without any special instructions. I already figured out that this editor apparently needs a BOM to understand that the encoding is actually UTF-8:

```
with codecs.open(r'c:\configfile.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as cf:
        cf.write("""Test1
Test2 öäüß
Test3""")
```

Now I noticed that with this code all newlines are written as 0x0a instead of 0x0d 0x0a, which the Windows Editor doesn't recognize, so it shows everything in one single line.

Long story short: What is a safe way to write a multiline unicode text string to a file that can be opened and edited with the Windows Editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Python 3, you can simply use

```
with open(r'c:\configfile.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as cf:
    ...
```

which will open the file in "text" mode. That will use the correct line ending for the OS on which you run the script.

`io.open()` works the same way. `codecs.open()` always uses binary more, no translation of line endings will happen.

In Python 2, you could achieve the same effect by using `wt` as mode.

Comment: Stupid of me. It was old Python 2.7 code, which I reused in Python 3 and simply overlooked the fact that I can now use open instead of codecs.open. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: In Python 3, `io.open is open`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution myself ... simply using io.open instead of codecs.open with the same parameters fixes the newline character issue:

```
with io.open(r'c:\configfile.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as cf:
        cf.write("""Test1
Test2 öäüß
Test3""")
```